# Trying to compile TPC-H Benchmark and is returned this error ld: library not found for -lgcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, benchmarking

I'm trying to compile the TPC-H Benchmark and when I made make, is returned the following error:

```
gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o build.o build.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o driver.o driver.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o bm_utils.o bm_utils.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o rnd.o rnd.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o print.o print.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o load_stub.o load_stub.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o bcd2.o bcd2.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o speed_seed.o speed_seed.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o text.o text.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o permute.o permute.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64    -c -o rng64.o rng64.c

gcc -g -DDBNAME=\"dss\" -DLINUX -DORACLE -DTPCH -DRNG_TEST -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O -o dbgen build.o driver.o bm_utils.o rnd.o print.o load_stub.o bcd2.o speed_seed.o text.o permute.o rng64.o -lm

ld: library not found for -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dbgen] Error 1
```

I made a search for trying to fix this and I don't found it any help yet. Somebody can help me please?

Comment: It seems that gcc is not found

Comment: Yes, but when I compile other programs gcc work's well. The strange thing is that when I made a search on this library, I don't find nothing. And the problem occurs only in my computer, because when I compile on a friend's computer the error don't occurs.

Comment: Have you done `which gcc` in order to be sure that you use the gcc version you think. Once I had a big mess between the gcc installed with the distribution and the one installed later. Huge gap of version.

Comment: please post the actual makefile contents  All the currently posted is saying is that the link step failed.

Answer (score 0):

try using gcc-5 on your makefile. i had the same problem with tpc-h.